# DataReader.GetGuid is throwing The method or operation is not implemented error

Tags: c#, .net, datareader

This is my code

```
try
                {
                    using (SafeDataReader reader = await this.SqlDataService.GetReaderAsync(command).ConfigureAwait(false))
                    {
                        while (reader != null && await reader.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                        {
                            response.Items.Value.Add(new SqlGetAllSitesResponse
                            {
                                SiteID = reader.GetGuid(reader.GetOrdinal("SiteID")),
                                URL = reader.GetString("URL"),
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    response.Success = false;
                    response.ErrorMessage = e.Message;
                }
```

it is throwing The method or operation is not implemented error. i do not understand the reason.please help.

Comment: Well, most likely the method is not implemented. Not entirely sure what else we can tell you here. `SafeDataReader`, from where did you get this type?

Comment: Have you verified if it is `reader.GetOrdinal` or `reader.GetGuid` that is throwing?

Comment: it is referenced from MetaData of other project

Comment: i got the point it was not implemented in that project and was throwing exception

Comment: Thanks @LasseVågsætherKarlsen

Comment: This error message strongly suggests that the method is not implemented. That is, the author of `SafeDataReader` chose not to properly implement the `GetGuid` override.